# Ошибка при получении id ImageView внутри фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, imageview, fragment-manager

Необходимо сделать snapshot, обработать изображение и поместить полученный Bitmap в `ImageView`, находящийся в фрагменте.

Ошибка возникает с получением `id` данного `ImageView` (получаю null). Насколько я понимаю - не работает `.getView` внутри `onSnapshotReady`. Как решить данную дилемму?

```
GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
   Bitmap src;
   Fragment frag2;
   @Override
   public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
       src = snapshot;

       ftran = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
       ftran.replace(R.id.FoFragment, fragimage).commit();

       frag2 = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.FoFragment);
       ((ImageView) frag2.getView().findViewById(R.id.MainImage)).setImageBitmap(src);
       }
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы реплейсите

```
ftran.replace(R.id.FoFragment, fragimage).commit();
```

вставляете fragimage в контейнер а потом пытаетесь найти frag2 у которого как я понимаю нет view из-за того что он не на экране, тут вы и получаете null.

Comment: ImageView - MainImage к которому я пытаюсь достучаться находиться внутри fragimage.xml. Его я добавляю на экран с помощью реплейса. Если закоментить данную строку ((ImageView) frag2.getView().findViewById(R.id.MainImage)).setImageBitmap(src);  программа работает исправно и на экране можно наблюдать пустой MainImage